# Sorting on unordered_sets

Tags: sorting, c++11, unordered-set

I have a list of items that are created each frame and need to be sorted.
Each Item's first member variable to sort by is an `unordered_set`.

I've moved this to an ordered set everywhere in the system so I can sort it in the list of items. But I'm suffering a performance hit in another are of the code foe this.

Bearing in mind that each item will be destroyed and be recreated on a per-frame basis, is there anything I can do to hold these in `unordered_set`s and sort them?

```
class item
{
    public:
    unordered_set< int > _sortUS;
    int _sortI;
    //Other members to sort
    bool operator<( const item& that ) const
    {
        if( _sortI != that._sortI )
        {
            return _sortI < that._sortI;
        }
        else if( _sortUS != that._sortUS )
        {
            return ??? // this is what I need. I don't know how to compare these without converting them to sets
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: The question is not 100% clear - you want to sort a (conceptual) sequence of `unsorted_set`s?

Comment: I have a list of items that I need to sort based on their member variables. One of the member variables to be compared in this sorting is an `unordered_set`. I just wanted to make it clear that I own the item's comparison operator, so I can make changes to how the operator compares `unordered_set`s.

Comment: So apparently you know enough to implement an ordering predicate (like `operator <`) on the items. I am still unclear what the question is - do you have a "less than" criterion for the `unorderd_set`s which you have trouble expressin in code (if so, please add it to the question), or is it something else?

Comment: So I've added a minimal explanation class of the code I'm trying to work with. The "less_than criterion" is what I was hoping to get help with, cause I do not have one.

Comment: So, basically your ordering on the two sets is defined as `lexicographical_compare(sort(uo1), sort(uo2))`? Also, if you are re-creating and destroying items very often you really want to make sure to reuse the memory of the `sets`. So instead of destroying them, assign to them.

Comment: Yeah pretty much, as I stated in the question, I've currently switched these into being `set`s so I can just use an `operator<` to compare. But I'm taking a performance hit on insertion. Is there some magic that I can do to sort `unordered_set`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `std::unordered_set<Key, Hash>` for arbitrary hashable `Key`, you could define

```
template<class Key, class Hash = std::hash<Key>>
bool operator< (std::unordered_set<Key, Hash> const& L, std::unordered_set<Key, Hash> const& R)
{
    return std::lexicographical_compare(
        begin(L), end(L), begin(R), end(R), 
        [](Key const& kL, Key const& kR) {
        return Hash()(kL) < Hash()(kR);     
    });
}
```

which will use the ordering on hash indices of `Key`. You can then define an ordering on `item`

```
bool operator< (item const& L, item const& R)
{
     return std::tie(L.sortI, L.sortUS) < std::tie(R.sortI, R.sortUS);
}
```

and `std::tie` will make a `std::tuple` out of references to the members of your `item` so that you can use the `operator<` from `std::tuple`.

**NOTE**: you can easily prove that the above comparison is a StrictWeakOrder (a requirement for `std::sort`) since both the `std::tuple` comparison and the `lexicographical_compare` have this property.

However, the ordering of `unordered_set` is very unusual in other respects.

- the hashed key index doesn't correspond to the order in which you iterate over elements (there is some modulo operation that maps hashed keys to indices in the container)
- adding elements to an `unordered_set` can result in rehashing and invalidation of previous orderering

Comment: Can you help me understand what the `Hash` command in your lambda is doing, I don't understand how that would help us maintain a _strict weak ordering_ (or even what that's doing in general.)

Comment: @JonathanMee In general, elements in an `unordered_set` don't have an `operator<` defined (your `int` has, but that's an exception). The only assumption you can make is that they can be hashed to an integral number. So you can define an ordering based on that. The `Hash()(kL)` command creates a function object of type `Hash` and calls it with argument `kL`.